# Issues nfs mounting a server

Tags: bash, nfs

I have a script that simply nfs mounts a server in udf file system. The mounting works on some occasions and on others it doesn't. When it doesn't it prints the following to my command line :

```
Timeout expired , aborting ...
```

The script is simple (can't disclose it). 
Do you know on what scenario would nfs mount timeout like that ? does that have anything to do with nfs server setting, short expiration period in the nfs configuration files ?

Comment: Sounds like a networking issue possibly.

Comment: @EtanReisner  could you elaborate on what possibly could be the cause for that scenario

Comment: General networking problems. Slowness due to flooded links. Overloaded firewalls/proxies/etc. dropping packets (counting on retransmission to keep things moving). A firewall that is only blocking you *sometimes* because of dynamically added and removed blocking rules (from things like `fail2ban`, etc.). Any number of other possibilities. Capture the network traffic when it works and when it doesn't and see how they differ.

Comment: Thank you for clarification